# Split screen in html according to checkbox inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four `checkboxes` ,clicking any of them returns respective html code from server. I want that on selecting 2 `checkboxes` screen should split in 2, similarly on selecting 3 `checkboxes` into 3.
how to write logic using `Jquery`, `HTML` and `CSS`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#go").click(function () {

        $("#output1").html('');
        $("#output2").html('');
        $("#output3").html('');
        $("#output4").html('');




        if ($('#getdisabledusers').prop("checked") == true)
        {
            $("#output1").html("<img src='http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif'  width='200' height='200' />");
            $("#box1").addClass("checkedbox");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/MVC_client/getdisabledusers",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#output1").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

Here i have one of my method in `JS`. Output1, output2, output3.... are the four divs. If `checkbox` is true , an ajax call will be there to return output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the thing you want using css `display:table` and `display:table-cell`: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g5g4es5m/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>option 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>option 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>option 3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>option 4</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  display:table;

  section{
    display:none;
    &.show{
      display:table-cell;
    }
    &:nth-child(1){
      background-color:red;
    }
    &:nth-child(2){
      background-color:yellow;
    }
    &:nth-child(3){
      background-color:blue;
    }
    &:nth-child(4){
      background-color:green;
    }
  }
}
.checkbox-container{
  text-align:center;
  .input-box{
    display:inline-block;
  }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var index=$(this).parent().index();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('section').eq(index).addClass('show');
    //your ajax call goes here
  }
  else{
    $('section').eq(index).removeClass('show');
  }
});
```